# return value from puppeteer page.evaluate()

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

So, I have a function that returning `page` that needed by next function:

```js
async function browser(){
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'], headless: false, devtools : true});
        const incog = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
        const page = await incog.newPage();

            await page.goto('web')
            .then(function(){
       page.evaluate(function(){
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('input[name ="username"]').val("a");
                $('input[name ="password"]').val("b");
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#loginbtn').click();
                });
            });
        });
      });

      await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil : 'load'});
      return page;
```

So, I pass the result value `browser()` by doing 
`browser().then(result => nextFunction(result)`
that eventually passing page into `nextFunction()`

```js
async function nextFunction(page){
    await page.goto('web')
       .then(function(){
        var msg = "Test : \n\n";
        page.evaluate(function(){
            var num = 1;
            $('.card').each(function(i, e){
                msg += "======= Activity "+num+" ========\n";
                msg += "Subject : " + $(this).find('.name').text() + "\n";
                msg += "Due : " + $(this).find('.date').text() + "\n";
                msg += "===== End Activity "+num+" ======\n\n";
                num++;
            });
        });
        console.log(msg);
       });
}
```

I tried to print `msg` from `nextFunction()`, but it only print `Test:`

What am I try to achieve is :
Get `msg` result or assign variable from return value of `nextFunction()`

Is there any solution or better way to do this?

Comment: `page.evaluate(function(){` must be awaited or `.then`ned. Using `.then()` syntax with Puppeteer is going to be painful. I suggest `async`/`await`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. For a cleaner code and easier troubleshooting, pick a lane, either async/await or chaining with `then`. Using both makes the code difficult to read. async/await is more readable and less tricky for error handling. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
2. To see `console.log` in `evaluate`, listen on 'console' event:

```js
const page = await browser.newPage();
page.on('console', msg => console.log(msg.text()));
```

3. `page.evaluate` context is separate from Puppeteer, so evaluate's `msg` will be `undefined`. Move the `msg` to evaluate and then return the result back to puppeteer.

```js
let msg = await page.evaluate(function(){
   let msg = "Test : \n\n";
   let num = 1;
   $('.card').each(function(i, e){
      msg += "======= Activity "+num+" ========\n";
      msg += "Subject : " + $(this).find('.name').text() + "\n";
      msg += "Due : " + $(this).find('.date').text() + "\n";
      msg += "===== End Activity "+num+" ======\n\n";
      num++;
   });
   return msg;
});
```